# Switching plone themes according to visitor's screen size

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, themes, plone, skin

For plone 4.2.5 is there a non-complicated way to set up theme switching between desktop/mobile versions based on visitors screen size? 
Something like "if less than 640x480 then" serve the mobile version ? 
Talking about 2 non-Diazo themes for instance?

What is ++skin++ for skin switching, may it work?

I am quite new to plone and not really a programmer so a "sane" solution would be really appreciated !

Answer (score 4):

Take a look in portal_css (via the Zope Management Interface) and search for "mobile." In the ""CSS Media" field, you'll find:

```
handheld, screen and (max-device-width: 480px)
```

This sets up a media query that causes browsers to use the mobile.css stylesheet if they know (admit) they are a handheld device or if they have a screen width of 480px or less. This is all done through completely standard CSS, and you may use the same principles to achieve completely different page designs for different screen widths. There are several great books on responsive design ("responsive" is the magic word). You may customize this stylesheet, or add your own media query style sheets.

You can also see a thorough and popular use of media queries and responsive design in "Twitter Bootstrap," which provides all sorts of class selectors that you may use to change designs at various screen widths. A bootstrap example is included with the newer version of plone.app.theming that is included with Plone 4.3.

Note, if you want design to change when you reduce a window size (not just the screen size), use "max-width" rather than "max-device-width."

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but the point is that I am short on time so going into learning CSS right now is not the best thing for me now I guess. The idea of  switching two themes came out from this product description :  http://plone.org/products/redturtle.subsites [see the "Apply the theme (AKA get a Subsite)"   section]     which describes the possibility of using Apache rules and ++skin++ in the url. So I was thinking one could set up some rule to check for the screen/window size and then change the skin in plone to the mobile one.

Comment: If that solution exists then it would be the right thing for me now I guess,because there are two specific themes that I want to use for this and I want/need to concentrate now more on adding/building content to the site instead of dealing with technical side.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. However, you should look into responsive design and media queries. I suspect you can achieve what you want using standards compliant CSS in a single theme.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but the point is that I am short on time so going into learning CSS right now is not the best thing for me now I guess. The idea of  switching two themes came out from this product description :  http://plone.org/products/redturtle.subsites [see the "Apply the theme (AKA get a Subsite)"   section]     which describes the possibility of using Apache rules and ++skin++ in the url. So I was thinking one could set up some rule to check for the screen/window size and then change the skin in plone to the mobile one.

Comment: If that solution exists then it would be the right thing for me now I guess,because there are two specific themes that I want to use for this and I want/need to concentrate now more on adding/building content to the site instead of dealing with technical side.

Answer (score 2):

http://plone.org/products/collective.themeswitcher/

This is an alternative implementation you can use. From the description:

This addon has been designed to easily support new switcher. At the moment the only switcher that is implemented is the "mobile switcher" based on user agent from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ (python version).